# Corrupted save file

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Something just went wrong with my ksp persistent.sfs (and quicksave.sfs) files. I launched the program like always, loaded everything just fine, made a rocket perfectly ok, then tried to launch and the game just hangs in there. The kerbals move and I can keep clicking but I can't switch menus and everything is in a suspended state.

I restarted and tried to just open an old ship but when I click on load, it hangs again. I had an archived version of my persistent.sfs file and tried it and it works but I kinda wish I knew what went wrong so I can maybe manually fix the persistent file. Would anyone maybe recognize some value in the file that is screwed up?

Here is a link to the diff between the good and bad copies:

[The repeated lines are the diff with the top always being the corrupted file.](http://pastebin.com/sjjm96Cw)

Comment: +1 for the diff, but it looks like a game bug. Save is a text file. If it's corrupted, then ships may fail to load, or get eaten by "save kraken", or explode on sight. Kerbals may die or return to life, and so on. But it should have absolutely no effect on things as fundamentals as menus. Some orbits got "Not a Number" in their Semi-major Axis data and that's a bit troubling, but it should explode ships rather than hang the game (if anything).

Comment: yup, that was my first guess so I tried turning them all into their previous value. i gave up and went back to my old file. all works. who knows what it was. it's a very hard bug to reproduce so i won't even go into trying to get it fix. thanks anyways!